# Composing functions with multiple arguments vs multiple argument lists

Tags: scala, function-composition, scala-2.12

Given the following example, I can see that it makes a difference, if I try to compose a function with multiple argument lists or just multiple arguments. I fail to see why it's not consistent.

```scala
val foo: Int => Int => Int = ???
foo.curried.andThen(???) // KO
foo.tupled.andThen(???) // KO
foo.andThen(???) // OK
val bar: (Int, Int) => Int = ???
bar.curried.andThen(???) // OK
bar.tupled.andThen(???) // OK
bar.andThen(???) // KO
```

Why is the Scala compiler not able to handle `bar` as a function, which I can `compose`/ call `andThen` on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to implement `Function2.compose` because the argument would have to be a function that returns two values (to pass on to `Function2.apply`). The Scala language does not support multiple return values so there is nothing that the compiler can do about it.

Implementing `Function2.andThen` would be possible, but the paradigm is chaining a value through multiple functions and that is not possible with `Function2` because of the same issue with return values.

Comment: yet, returning a tuple for compose would be possible.

Comment: @StefanK. It is certainly possible, but it feels cleaner and simpler to keep `compose` and `andThen` restricted to functions with a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found it - `scala.Function2` doesn't implement `andThen` in contrast to `Function1`